# I have a error when I try to swich the old angular 2 router with the new Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the main app component and under the admin component I want to add subroutes like /admin/users, /admin/subscribers

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
@Routes[
new Route({
                path: '/admin/...',
                //name: 'Admin',
                component: AdminPage
            })
]
```

And this is the configuration for the admin component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'admin-Page',
    templateUrl: applicationPath + '/adminPage.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
    new Route({
        path: '/users',
        component: UsersPage,
        // name: 'Users',
        // useAsDefault:true
    }),
    new Route({
        path: '/subscribers',
        component: SubscribersPage,
        // name: 'Subscribers'
    })
]
```

...but the problem is that the application does not recognize the route
/admin/users. With the new router is this behaviour not supported
any more?  Does it just have a different syntax?

Comment: The error message says it's an error in `AppComponent` inline template:2:12 but your code doesn't include `AppComponent` nor the template. Please add the code of `AppComponent`.

Comment: I found the error I subcomponent used the deprecated router, also the new router supports the routes that are not final ? like '/admin/...' cause right now I'm receiving an unmatching route error for those ones ?

Comment: `/...` is not necessary in the new router anymore. For the error, ensure your routes in `@Routes([...])` are ordered so that the least specific come last.

Comment: Ok but I splited my routs between multiple components, this means that with the new @Routes I should bring all the routes in one place ?

Comment: No, that's not necessary but without seeing what routes and components we are talking about its difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: new Route({
                path: '/admin/...',
                //name: 'Admin',
                component: AdminPage
            }),
this was the main route and under the AdminPage I had subroutes
new Route({
        path: '/users',
        component: UsersPage,
        // name: 'Users',
        // useAsDefault:true
    }),
    new Route({
        path: '/subscribers',
        component: SubscribersPage,
        // name: 'Subscribers'
    }),
which are mapping to /admin/users or /admin/subscribers

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Can you please edit your question and add the code there (properly formatted if possible).

Comment: where should I add a piece of code to see the structure ? cause the application is preatty big already

Comment: I will add a new question for that

Comment: Can we discuss the basic principles using a simplified example with maybe only 3 components. Most should then be easy to translate to your actual project.

Comment: yes sure I will add a question with only 3 components

Comment: I added the configuration here, I cannot post another question for 90 minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113120/discussion-between-nicu-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: As mentioned `/...` isn't necessary anymore. Besides that it looks fine. What is your current error message?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `/...` in RC.1 router anymore to indicate there are child-routes.

Comment: so how will angular knows that component has SubRoutes or not ? and whats the alternate for the same, Better is if you provide any working example or some code showing routing in RC.1

Comment: It doesn't need to know in advance. That's one of the main reason for the new RC.1 router because this caused issues with lazy loading of routes. When the component for a route is loaded then the routes are read if it has some and then the router knows there are some.

Comment: Sure there still **is** child routing. You just don't need to configure it explicitely at the parent. Just configure routes at the child components and be done.

Comment: than how will we have to call that child routes ? is there any documentation or article which will explain bit more about child routing in angular2 ?

Comment: Just navigate to it. I'm not sure where you see a problem with this.